# How would I write a method that takes an object arraylist parameter and performs a method that is in a superclass

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, polymorphism

Ok so the code i have is

```
public static void showCenter(ArrayList<TestPoly2> array){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(array.center());
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to go about this problem but this is what I have come up with from sitting here thinking.

```
.center()
```

is a method from the superclass

I want to be able to create multiple objects from multiple different classes and store them in the same arraylist if this is possible.

Any pointers or tips are helpful : )

Comment: array.get(i).center()?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  `.center()` is in the superclass of _what_ exactly?

Comment: Don't declare your parameter as an `ArrayList<TestPoly2>` -- any method you write for that will work equally well with any of the kinds of Lists, so declare `public static void showCenter(List<TestPoly2> list)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `foreach` type loop

```
for (TestPoly2 elem : array) {
   System.out.println(elem.center());
}
```

this is of course the same result as doing a traditional loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(array.get(i).center());
    // or
    // TestPoly2 elem = array.get(i);
    // System.out.println(elem.center());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful! sorry the question wasnt very clear but this did help me out alot.